# abc='^.{2,1000}$' meaning in shell script?

Tags: scripting

I got a script & found this parameter. what will happen by using this in my script. I tried to find the way but didn't get any specific result.

abc='^.{2,1000}$'

Comment: How this variable is used? Looks like regexp

Comment: @Alexey Ten... You r right. I got an answer. thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a *regular expression*, so probably it is.

The regex `^.{2,1000}$` will match a value whose total length is at least 2 and at most 1000.